# Getting value from data-value (webdriver selenium / java)

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, java

I have the following HTML code

```
<div class="mbsc-sc-whl-c" style="height:40px;margin-top:-21px;">
   <div class="mbsc-sc-whl-sc" style="top: 0px; transform: translate3d(0px, -1520px, 0px); transition: -webkit-transform 300ms cubic-bezier(0.19, 1, 0.22, 1) 0s; margin-top: -80px;
       <div role="option" tabindex="-1" aria-selected="true" class="mbsc-sc-itm   mbsc-btn-e mbsc-sc-itm-sel" data-index="8" data-val="8" style="height:40px;line-height:40px;">08
       <div role="option" tabindex="0" aria-selected="true" class="mbsc-sc-itm   mbsc-btn-e mbsc-sc-itm-sel" data-index="9" data-val="9" style="height:40px;line-height:40px;">09
```

I would like to extract the value of `data-val="9"` and assign it to a String variable.

I tried

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@role='option']//*[@tabindex = '0']")).getText();
```

and I am getting `"Unable to locate element"`

Hope to have advice. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

QA automation engineers face this issue while automating user interface testing scenarios.

Below is the code that can be used to fetch the value of data-val="9":

String text = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@role='option' and @tabindex = '0']")).getText();

or

String text =  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='mbsc-sc-whl-sc']/div[@data-val='9']")).getText();

Comment: Thanks @Anand, it did help. However, do you mind sharing with me what is the difference between your code and mine ? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I checked your HTML code and the java code. I have found a few issues in the codes.

```
<div class="mbsc-sc-whl-sc" style="top: 0px; transform: translate3d(0px, -1520px, 0px); transition: -webkit-transform 300ms cubic-bezier(0.19, 1, 0.22, 1) 0s; margin-top: -80px;
```

1. In this line above you have not closed the `<div>` tag
2. `transform: translate3d(0px, -1520px, 0px);` this style and `margin-top: -80px;` this attribute doesn't allow the text to be displayed within the visible area of the page. Hence Selenium isn't able to get the content of the `<div>` tag.

Change it to,

```
<div class="mbsc-sc-whl-sc" style="top: 0px; transform: translate3d(0px, -1520px, 0px); transition: -webkit-transform 300ms cubic-bezier(0.19, 1, 0.22, 1) 0s; margin-top: -80px;>
```

Now about your java code:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@role='option']//*[@tabindex = '0']")).getText();
```

In this line above the Xpath is wrong and hence you are getting the error Unable to locate element".

Here is the correct xpath you can use: `//div[@role='option' and @tabindex='0']`

Here is my HTML with which I tested:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="mbsc-sc-whl-c" style="height:40px;margin-top:-21px;">
        <div class="mbsc-sc-whl-sc" style="top: 0px; transition: -webkit-transform 300ms cubic-bezier(0.19, 1, 0.22, 1) 0s;">
            <div role=" option" tabindex="-1" aria-selected="true" class="mbsc-sc-itm   mbsc-btn-e mbsc-sc-itm-sel"
                data-index="8" data-val="8" style="height:40px;line-height:40px;">08</div>
            <div role="option" tabindex="0" aria-selected="true" class="mbsc-sc-itm   mbsc-btn-e mbsc-sc-itm-sel"
                data-index="9" data-val="9" style="height:40px;line-height:40px;">09
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Here is my Java + Selenium code which worked for me:

```
try {
    WebDriver driver;
    System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", System.getProperty("user.dir") + "//geckodriver");
    System.setProperty(FirefoxDriver.SystemProperty.BROWSER_LOGFILE, "FFLogs.txt");
    driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.get("http://localhost/1");
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    Thread.sleep(2000);
    String text = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@role='option' and @tabindex='0']")).getText();
    System.out.println("Your string: " + text);
    String text1 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@role='option' and @tabindex='0']")).getAttribute("data-val");
    System.out.println("Your attribute: " + text1);
    
    Thread.sleep(5000);
    driver.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Thanks @IAmMilimPatel. It did guide me to the correct direction